# How to check data exist in database or not while uploading large dataset using django

Tags: django, openpyxl

I am going to make a scripts that load excelsheet which contain 17000 rows to django model.
But, I don't get idea to check given data already exist or not in database efficiently.

```py
# models.py

# no fields value are unique here,

class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rollno=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```py
# views.py
def upload_script(request):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
    worksheet = wb["All DMAs"]
    
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
        datacollection=row[0:9]
        name=datacollection[0]
        address=datacollection[1]
        rollno=datacollection[2]
        age=datacollection[3]
   
      # everytime this call the database which load more time
       if(Student.objects.filter(name=name,address=address,rollno=rollno,age=age).first():
          continue

       student_obj=Student(
             name=name,
             address=address,
             rollno=rollno,
             age=age
          )
      student_list.append(student_obj)
      if len(student_list)>1000:
         Student.objects.bulk_create(student_list)
         student_list=[]
    Student.objects.bulk_create(student_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the backend db, one method would be to confirm a uniqueness constraint on relevant fields in the model and use `bulk_create`s `ignore_conflicts` parameter (see [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)).

Also, note the `batch_size` parameter that could remove

```
if len(student_list)>1000:
    Student.objects.bulk_create(student_list)
    student_list=[]
```

from your code.

`Student.objects.bulk_create(student_list,batch_size=1000,ignore_conflicts=True)`

Another potential solution, but with one db hit per object (though you're already doing that), would be to use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead of `filter`.

```py
student_obj=Student.objects.get_or_create(
    name=name,
    address=address,
    rollno=rollno,
    age=age
)
```

Neither solution is particularly elegant, especially if there's reason *not* to have a uniqueness constraint on any of the fields.